# Updating table without turning on the safe mode

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

```
A:
id | b_id | priority
1    1      1
2    1      2
3    2      1

B:
id
1
2
```

I want to update all rows from the `A` table having `b_id` specified - more specifically I want to swap values from `priority` columns.

This is what I have:

```
UPDATE A a1
INNER JOIN A a2
ON (a1.priority, a2.priority) IN ((1,2),(2,1))
SET a1.priority = a2.priority
WHERE a1.id = (SELECT a3.id FROM A a3 WHERE b_id = 1);
```

It doesn't work however, I am getting the

```
Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect. 0.00033 sec
```

error.

`A` table has primary key on `id` column.
`A` table has foreign key `b_id` to `B.id`.

What's wrong?

Comment: `(a1.priority, a2.priority) IN ((1,2),(2,1))` is this some new mysql feature? tuples?

Comment: `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;`

Comment: Also try to precede your tablename with schemaname

Comment: Well, it works as expected. I'd like to do this without turning off the safe update mode.